# Need help w/ JavaScript and creating an html table from array

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried everything I can find via google and nothing has worked correctly. Output is just a single row with all the contents of the array listed. What I need is a way to write the contents of an array but after 3 cells, automatically start a new line. I'll post the code I've made below as well as the question. (yes this is from an assignment. :( )

```
//***(8) place the words in the string "tx_val" in a table with a one pixel border,
//***    with a gray backgound. Use only three cells per row. Empty cells should contain
//***    the word "null". Show the table in the span block with id="ans8"

var count = i % 3;
var nrow = "";
var out = "<table border='1' bgcolor='gray'><tr>"
for (var i=0; i<txArr.length; i++)
{
    out += ("<td>" + txArr[i] + "</td>");
    count++;
    if (count % 3 == 0)
    {
        nrow += "</tr><tr>";
    }
}

document.getElementById('ans8').innerHTML = out + nrow;
```

Comment: No problem with having assignments posted here, so long as you state that this is the case. However, you could tell us what exactly you are having difficulties with...

Comment: Can you post a sample output for the array?

Comment: You don't need the `nrow` var, just change that line to `out += "</tr><tr>"` and you're half-way there.

Comment: Your code doesn't work? Please provide any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using an array over concatination

```
var html = [];
html.push("<table><tr>");
var i = 0;

for (var k in txArr)
{
    if(i>=3){
      i=0;
      html.push("</tr><tr>");
    }
    html.push("<td>" + txArr[k] + "</td>");
    i++;
}
html.push("</tr></table>");

document.getElementById('ans8').innerHTML = html.join('');

// wrapped in function
function arrayToTable(a,cols){
 var html = [];
    html.push("<table><tr>");
    var i = 0;

    for (var k in a)
    {
        if(i>=cols){
          i=0;
          html.push("</tr><tr>");
        }
        html.push("<td>" + a[k] + "</td>");
        i++;
    }
    html.push("</tr></table>");
    return html.join('')
}
document.getElementById('ans8').innerHTML = arrayToTable(txArr, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to print the `tr`'s inside the table (annd add a `</table>`!):

```
var count = i % 3; // btw. what's this??
var nrow = "";
var out = "<table border='1' bgcolor='gray'><tr>"
for (var i=0; i<txArr.length; i++)
{
    out += "<td>" + txArr[i] + "</td>";
    count++;
    if (count % 3 == 0)
        out += "</tr><tr>";
}
out += "</table>";

document.getElementById('ans8').innerHTML = out;
```

Comment: don't need the `nrow` variable anymore though; and isn't out reserved (I don't remember)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to write out the html, try manipulating the dom.  It seems much more straightforward to me.  Take a look at the following:

`var row = table.insertRow();`
 [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536457%28VS.85%29.aspx)
 [mdc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.insertRow)
`var cell = row.insertCell();`
 [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536455%28VS.85%29.aspx)
 [mdc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/tableRow.insertCell)
`var cellContent = document.createTextNode(txArr[i]);`
 [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536400%28VS.85%29.aspx)
 [mdc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode)
`cell.appendChild(cellContent);`
 [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535934%28VS.85%29.aspx)
 [mdc](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)

For deciding when to start a new row, just use the modulus operator (`%`
 [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f59bza0%28VS.94%29.aspx)
 [mdc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_%28Modulus%29)
) against `i`:

```
if (i % 3 == 0)
{
    row = table.insertRow()
}
```

You'd end up with something like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById("ans8");
var t = container.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
var row;
txArr.forEach(function (item, i)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        row = t.insertRow()
    }
    row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
});
```

I'll leave a little for you to figure out - border, background color, getting the word "null" in there.  It is *your* homework after all.  :-)

Also, for older browsers you'll need to [add Array.forEach in yourself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

It might be a tad easier to accomplish with something like

```
buffer = "<table>";
for(var r = 0; r < 10; r++){
   buffer += "<tr>";
   for(var c = 0; c < 3 ; c++){
      buffer += "<td>Cell: " + r + ":" + c + "</td>";
   }
   buffer += "</tr>";
}
buffer += "</table>";
 document.getElementById("ans8").innerHTML = buffer;
```

That would create a table 30 rows long by 3 columns for each row.

Answer (score 0):

you might be assigning values to "count" too early as you don't know what i is yet. and you are not spitting out the value of nrow anywhere... change it to out.

```
var count;
var nrow = "";
var out = "<table border='1' bgcolor='gray'><tr>"
for (var i=0; i<txArr.length; i++)

{
out += ("<td>" + txArr[i] + "</td>");
count++;
if (count % 3 == 0)
    {
    out += "</tr><tr>";
    }
}

 document.getElementById('ans8').innerHTML = out + nrow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I would split it up into 3 functions, for readability and maintenance.  These functions would consist of creating a cell, a row, and a table.   This definitely simplifies reading the code.  As I have not tested it, below is an example of what I would do.

```
function createTableCell(value) {
  return value == null? "<td>NULL</td>":"<td>" + value + "</td>";
}

function createTableRow(array) {
  var returnValue = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    returnValue = returnValue + createTableCell(array[i]);
  }
  return "<tr>" + returnValue + "</tr>";
}

function arrayToTable(array, newRowAfterNArrayElements) {
  var returnValue = "<table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + newRowAfterNArrayElements) {
     returnValue = returnValue + createTableRow(array.split(i, (i + newRowAfterNArrayElements) - 1));
  }
  return returnValue + "</table>";
}

document.getElementById("ans8").innerHTML = arrayToTable(txArr, 3);
```

In addition this makes your code much more dynamic and reusable.  Suppose you have an array you want to split at every 4 element.  Instead of hardcoding that you can simply pass a different argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a live example of doing this with [DOMBuilder](https://github.com/insin/DOMBuilder), and of using the same code to generate DOM Elements and an HTML String.

- http://jsfiddle.net/insin/hntxW/

Code:

```
var dom = DOMBuilder.elementFunctions;

function arrayToTable(a, cols) {   
  var rows = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i += cols) {
      rows.push(a.slice(i, i + cols));
  }
  return dom.TABLE({border: 1, bgcolor: 'gray'},
    dom.TBODY(
      dom.TR.map(rows, function(cells) {
        return dom.TD.map(cells);
      })
    )
  );
}

var data = [1, 2, null, 3, null, 4, null, 5, 6];

document.body.appendChild(arrayToTable(data, 3));
document.body.appendChild(
  dom.TEXTAREA({cols: 60, rows: 6},
    DOMBuilder.withMode("HTML", function() {
      return ""+arrayToTable(data, 3);
    })
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build from scratch...but there's a faster way.  Throw a grid at it.  The grid will take data in a string, array, json output, etc and turn it into a proper HTML outputted table and will allow you to extend it with sorting, paging, filtering, etc.

My personal favorite is [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net), but there are numerous others out there.

Once you get proficient, setting one of these up literally takes 5 minutes.  Save your brain power to cure world hunger, code the next facebook, etc....